# Flask, Babel and python - ImportError: No module named babel

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

Despite installing babel I am rather amused yet annoyed that Flask and Babel do not work.

```
pip install babel
pip install Flask-Babel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 8, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace//dashboard/app/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flaskext.babel import Babel
ImportError: No module named babel
```

Comment: Is it a typo: `from falskext.babel import Babel`. It shoulb be `from flask.ext.babel import Babel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
from flaskext.babel import Babel
```

to

```
from flask.ext.babel import Babel
```

Note the `.` before and after 'ext'. The syntax you are using is the old methodology of importing flask extensions. But for the past few versions, flask made it a standard way of importing extensions. Read the last paragraph [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/extensiondev/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
from flask_babel import Babel
```

I think it follows the convention that when the installation name is separated by a -, then imports can be done when replaced by an underscore